# Why Active Record doesn't send same data than schema.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, schema

I created a new **migration** to add a column named `transferred` to `advance_payments` table.

```
class AddTransferredToAdvancePayments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :advance_payments, :transferred , :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

After migrating, the column does exist in **schema.rb** :

```
  create_table "advance_payments", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
   ...
    t.boolean  "transferred",                                    default: false
   ...
  end
```

**Console**

But when I inspect an `AdvancePayment` object in console, there is no column named `transferred`

`AdvancePayment.last.transferred` or `AdvancePayment.last.transferred?`

> > NoMethodError: undefined method `transferred'

```
[1] pry(main)> AdvancePayment.last
  AdvancePayment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `advance_payments`.* FROM `advance_payments` ORDER BY `advance_payments`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<AdvancePayment:0x0000000747e468
 id: 107,
 ...
 // all columns except "transferred"



[10] pry(main)> AdvancePayment.has_attribute?(:transferred)
=> false
```

I tried to `db:migrate` and `db:schema:load` and I get the same result.
I also tried to `drop` than recreate db, close then reopen server nothings better.

Comment: How about `transferred?` and `transfrerred=` - do those exist?

Comment: Quit console and re-enter.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh  I edited my post. Doesn't work :/

Comment: @meta Doesn't work neither

Comment: Check your INNODB database and let us know if you see the column

Comment: @Maxence can you give me more details please ? I never heard about INNODB sorry :/

Comment: I meant just to check your local database directly, not through the Rails console, to make sure the column is indeed there.

Comment: @Maxence I checked and indeed the column doesn't exist. How could it be possible ? The migration has been run and the schema say that the column is present

Comment: Yes this is weird. When drop and recreate, other fields appear in database but `transferred` ? Also check your `database.yml` and make sure you are using the right adapter for your database. My database is postgres then my adapter is `postgresql` together with `gem 'pg'`

Comment: make sure your rails console is running for same database which your are expecting for. Then try running `rake db:migrate` after that in your console try running `reload!` or restart your rails console.

Comment: @SujayGavhane I just checked and it's the same db

Answer (score 0):

Cannot really explain why but edit `change` method by `up` and `down` resolved the issue

```
  def self.up
    add_column :advance_payments, :transferred , :boolean, default: false
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :advance_payments, :transferred
  end
```